# Specify priority between implict conversions

Tags: c++, hierarchy, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

I am trying to find a way to specify a hierarchy of *implicit* conversions between different types.

Suppose I have two types and a function overload for each:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

void f(A const& a){}
void f(B const& b){}
```

Now I have another class that it is implicitly convertible to both `A` and `B`

```
class C{
    A to_A()  const{return A{} ;}
    B to_B() const{return B{};}
    operator A() const{return to_A() ;}
    operator B() const{return to_B();}
};
```

As it is, I cannot use `f` directly because of ambiguity.

```
int main(){
    C c;
    f(c); // ambiguous, convert c to a, o c to b??
}
```

Let's also say that a conversion to `B` is more sensible given the option.

**Is there way to specify in `struct C` one of the two (`A` or `B`) as the preferred conversion?**, so that `main` compiles and is equivalent to `f(c.to_B());`

Full code here: https://godbolt.org/z/xvz71qEhK

Possible near solutions I discarded:

1. One obvious way is to make one conversions (to `A`) `explicit`, but I want that both conversion are implicit. Because there are other functions (not overloaded like `f`) where both conversion can be implicit.
2. At the place of call make the conversion explicit, `main(){f(c.to_B());}` The problem is that I am using this in generic template functions where the template parameter can be `A`, `B` or `C`.
3. For every ambiguous overload make a new overload `f(C const& c){return f(c.to_B());}`, the problem is that I have to do this for every overloaded functions that can take `A` or `B` and I have many of them. I can have tens of `f`-like functions, some of them with more than one argument (exploding number of combinations).

---

What I tried so far: I though that defining a hierarchy would help to select the *preferred* conversion, and that the operators of the leaf class would have preference, but it didn't remove de ambiguity.

https://godbolt.org/z/fYj7PP5GE

```
template<class CRTP>
struct base_to_A{
    operator A()  const{
        return static_cast<CRTP const&>(*this).to_A() ;
    }
};

class C : public base_to_A<C>{
    A to_A() const{return A{};}
    B to_B() const{return B{};}
public:
    operator B() const{return to_B();}
};
```

Playing with `public/protected/private` didn't help.

Comment: To me this seems more like a design problem rather than an implementation/code problem. Also remember that implicit conversions tend to make code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes, I started with `A` and `B` only and then added a new type that can play semantically as both. Ambiguity would be ok if the relation of `C` with `A` is `B` is equal, somehow I want to make `C` more related with `B` than `A` (for efficiency purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Use variants in the API, and dispatch to template implementations if needed.

Have a conversion function that knows which you prefer.

```
void f(std::variant<A,B,C> var1, std::variant<A,B,C> var2){
  return std::visit[&](auto& v1, auto& v2){
    f_impl(v1,v2);
  }, prefer_variant_convert<A,B>(var1), prefer_variant_convert<A,B>(var2) );
}
```

we take in variants, we run code to convert them to preferred variant types in order, then we generate exponential amounts of code to unnpack the variants.

Or, template version:

```
void f(auto var1, auto var2){
  return f_impl( prefer_convert<A,B>(var1), prefer_convert<A,B>(var2) );
}
```

the `prefer_convert<Ts...>(T0)` returns `T0` if it is in `Ts...`, otherwise the first of the `Ts` that `T0` can convert to.  It shouldn't be hard to write.

Comment: Interesting idea. I guess this has some runtime cost, and I need to replicate for every function that is `f`-like. An idea to work on is maybe also consider a cast operation to `std::variant<A, B>`, I have to think about it.

Comment: @alfc the second does not have runtime cost as far as I can tell.  Both generate exponential code for conversion, but the second only if called exponentially different ways.

Answer (score 0):

*This doesn't answer the question in general, it is only in particular case and considering a certain design.*

A partial solution that works in some designs:
If `C` can be implemented in terms of `B` alone and publicly, the conversion (actually a cast to `B`) will be preferred:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A{};
struct B{};

void f(A const& a){std::puts("A");}
void f(B const& b){std::puts("B");}

class C : public B{
    A to_A() const{return A{} ;}
//    B to_B() const{return *this;} // not used
public:
    operator A() const{return to_A() ;}
//  operator B() const{return to_B();} // not needed, will never be called anyway
};

int main(){
    C c;
    f(c); // preferres B
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nnMPGbjeM